# Why does my Beautifulsoup element stay the same if element on the website changes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests, bs4
import time


def get_tesla_price():
    website = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/"
    res = requests.get(website)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elem = soup.select("span[class='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)']")

    price = elem[0].getText()
    print(price)

for _ in range(10):
    get_tesla_price()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Above is some code which should scrape the current value of the tesla stock. If you run it you will see that `price` stays the same for all 10 function calls. But if you check the website in `website` you see that the price of the stock changes almost every second.

Why, every time when i call my function, `price` is the same value?

Comment: Because the value is got updated via JavaScript ! Call the api directly which feed the render

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your user agent, yahoo detects you are a robot, add user agent in headers:

```py
def get_tesla_price():
    website = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/"
    res = requests.get(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elem = soup.select("span[class='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)']")

    price = elem[0].getText()
    res.close()
    print(price)
```

Or you can do it with just one module requests-html:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time

session = HTMLSession()

def get_tesla_price():
    website = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/"
    r = session.get(website)
    price = r.html.find("span[class='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)']", first=True)
    print(price.text)
    

for _ in range(20):
    get_tesla_price()
    time.sleep(1)
```

output:

```sh
682.66
682.66
682.53
682.53
682.53
682.65
682.62
682.69
682.65
682.71
682.71
682.83
682.83
682.83
682.83
682.79
682.79
682.79
682.79
682.80
```